# Database design for sport scoring system

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working on database for scoring system for my friend. I have table with **games** and second table with **names of sports** (footbal, tenis, floorball). I want to store scores of the games but I don't know how to design database for specific needs of scores.

**For example:**
Football score - 1:2, 2:2 (1st and 2nd half)
Tenis sets - 6:4, 7:6
Floorbal - 1:0, 3:0, 3:2 (1st, 2nd and 3rd part of the game)

I need this score linked to games table, but I need specific table columns for storing score for every game.

**I think about:**

1. Multiple tables and and foreign key, but this is not possible in mysql.
2. Then I think about storing data in json in one row and then parse it specifically based on sport, but probably this is not very good solution.

The only problem from my point of view is:

### **How create table/s for storing scores in different format based on type of sport?**

Thank you for any help

Comment: Bulva, to improve your experience here, please narrow you question down so we can focus on a smaller chunk

Comment: Add 1 more table scores and connect it with games( but u will need one more table for teams of sport) and playing against(so lets say barcelona vs real madrid ) so that table can have id of team 1 id of team 2 and score for 1 and second half

Comment: Thx for reply Oncodeeater. This is easy for football, but how create it for tennis, where you need store every set? Footbal score (1:1), tennis score (6:4, 6:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
match_id | period_id | team1_score | team2_sore
       1 |         1 |           1 |          2
       1 |         2 |           2 |          2
       2 |         1 |           6 |          4   
       2 |         2 |           7 |          6   
       3 |         1 |           1 |          0
       3 |         2 |           3 |          0
       3 |         3 |           3 |          2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. I can't imagine appropriate structure of table.

Answer (score 0):

You mention MySQL, so it appears that you want to develop a relational database.

The first step is to define the relations.  Based on your example.

1. A game has one sport.
2. A sport has zero or more games.
3. A game has one or more period scores.
4. A period score has one game.

Based on these relationships, we can define 3 tables.

```
Sport
-----
Sport ID
Sport name
...

Game
----
Game ID
Sport ID
Game name

PeriodScore
-----------
PeriodScore ID
Game ID
Period
Score
```

The primary ID fields are known as blind keys.  They are auto-incrementing integers.  Their sole purpose is to tie the game with the sport, and the period scores with the game.  Otherwise, they have no meaning at all.  The primary ID fields are the primary (clustering) keys of their respective tables.

The Sport ID in the Game table is a foreign key.  This key points back to the Sport table, so you can get the name of the sport.  You can create a unique index on (Sport ID, Game ID) if you ever want a list of the games for a particular sport.

The Game ID in the PeriodScore table is another foreign key.  You must create a unique index on (Game ID, PeriodScore ID) so that you can retrieve the period scores in the correct order.

When you want to create a relational database, you first define the relationships, then go through a process of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks for great answer. This is the same as @Strawberry, maybe in PeriodScore should be team1_score as in Strawberry table, if I undestand structure good. Or is it better way how identify score for particular team (e.g. first score in table for first team and so on)?